# WPF Datagrid doesnot update UI on ItemsSource Changed

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, observablecollection, wpfdatagrid

I am binding my observablecollection to CollectionViewSource which has SortDescriptions. On initial load everything loads fine and sorting can be done.

I have a reset button on which i am trying to refresh the changes in the grid with re fetching observablecollection and binding to ItemSource. Once i do the rebind the sorting doesnot work.

Below is my collectionviewsource,

```
<CollectionViewSource
            x:Key="BuildLineSource"
            IsLiveSortingRequested="True"
            Source="{Binding BuildLineCollection,
                             UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
                <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="BuildLineCategory.Category" />
            </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            <CollectionViewSource.LiveSortingProperties>
                <system:String>ExecutePriority</system:String>
            </CollectionViewSource.LiveSortingProperties>
            <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
                <componentModel:SortDescription PropertyName="ExecutePriority" />
            </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        </CollectionViewSource>
```

Below is the code i am calling on Constructor and also on Reset click,

```
private void GetBuildLines()
    {
        BuildLineCollection?.Clear();
        BuildLineCollection = _buildLineData.GetBuildLines();           
        ((INotifyPropertyChanged)BuildLineCollection).PropertyChanged +=
            (x, y) => BuildLineUpdated();
    }
```

Comment: After clearing BuildLineCollection you are then creating a new ObservableCollection and replacing its binding, and you are not actually performing a physical rebinding.  I would suggest that you do not replace BuildLineCollection, and just repopulate its content from the response to GetBuildLines() via many calls to Add().

Comment: Here in the code above the property "BuildLineCollection" is an ObservableCollection which is binded to CollectionViewSource. So when Reset button is clicked the "GetBuildLines" is called again which clears the collections and populates it.

Comment: what class does the above posted method GetBuildLines belong to? what is _buildLineData? what does its own method GetBuildLines do?

Comment: @vinay no, you are clearing it and then replacing it with another item. This is your problem. The original object that you binded to is no longer referenced by anything so will just be cleared up

Comment: @LordWilmore thank you. That solved the problem